# What is the exact effect that affection has on companions?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know that in general, a higher affection score raises the chance for a successful crew skill check and reduces the time to completion, but what I'm looking for here is hard numbers so I can decide whether or not buying a bunch of gifts to raise my companion's affection is worth it to me?

What I'm particularly interested in is the following at each affection level (0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, and 10000):

- % reductions in skill time
- Bonus to skill crit rate

If there are any effects other than that, I'd love to hear about those too! This obviously can be difficult, particularly calculating the crit rate, since it would require a lot of data points. But if you can find external research on it or can convince your guild to help you out with data points ([much like some seemed to do with calculating average values for various crew skill missions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44155/3062)), that'd be awesome!

Comment: Some characters will allow some... "favours" of the bow chicka wow wow kind

Comment: @RafaelCelerier I thought that wasn't affected or effected by affection.

Comment: I haven't seen anything except rumors about affection changing crit rate, and since crit rates are so rare, I don't think anybody really has done enough data-mining to prove it. Until Bioware says something about it, I'm skeptical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a rough rule of thumb, every 750 affection is worth roughly a 1% reduction in completion time on crew skill tasks.

Edit: Comments indicate that the first 450 points of companion affection are worth 2% off the top, and that further affection follows the 1%/750 formula. I haven't seen the exact data set, but this does fit the patterns I've seen closely enough to be plausible.

Comment: How sure are you of this? My companion with 4k reputation seems to be taking more than 5% off the time.

Comment: @Sterno what profession and which companion?

Comment: Treasure Hunting, and T7. I'll try to run some numbers tonight.

Comment: I stand corrected. My affection was higher than I thought. 5638 affection for a 12 minute, 12 second mission dropped to about 11 minutes 4 seconds. Not exactly what you said, but not far off.

Comment: The number I quoted **is** approximate.

Comment: Okay, I found a forum post that backs up the 750 thing, except you start where 450 causes 98%, and go up by 750 for every 1% (so 97% at 1200, 96% at 1950, etc) from there. That seems to get my observed results really close to the formula. If you update your answer to say to start counting at 450 = 98%, I'll award you the bounty assuming nothing else comes in.